# Reading from a socket

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration, mq

I am trying to read data from a particular socket on a host and port.

I donot want to use java based server code that would listen on the port to read the data. But I want to use something which supports HA (High Availability) and scalability like Apache Camel.

Is there a way where I can read the port and push the data on a queue through a CAMEL

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [camel-netty](https://camel.apache.org/netty) and [camel-jms](https://camel.apache.org/jms) components to that kind of work.